# Pass clicked element's attributes in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how can I pass an element's attributes which I clicked in a different function.

To be specific I have a dozen of elements with the same `className = online`. However each of the elements has one unique ID which I assigned to them dynamically.

I use `$(document).on` because I want to  listen on the `document`, for a click because the elements with `className=online` are created dynamically too.

```
$(document).on("click", ".online", isInPrivateChat);
```

How can I then in a different function for example

```
function TakeTheidfTheElement(){
  //take the id of the element i clicked
}
```

I know I should use jquery method `.attr('id')` but cant really make it work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/375/)**.

You could simply get the `id` from the callback function `isInPrivateChat` using `this.id` like :

```
function isInPrivateChat(){
   alert( this.id );
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".online", isInPrivateChat);

function isInPrivateChat(){
   console.log( this.id );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='online' id='id_1'>Btn 1</button>
<button class='online' id='id_2'>Btn 2</button>
<button class='online' id='id_3'>Btn 3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Carry the ID through:

```
$(document).on("click", ".online", function() {
    isInPrivateChat($(this).attr('id')); /* <-- get id and pass it in */
});
```

then

```
function TakeTheidfTheElement(idPassed){
  // do something with idPassed
}
```

For the record, Zacaria's answer is the better option - showing this is how you can use `.attr('id')`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the whole element to a sub function and there you can use JQuery or straight javascript to get the properties of the element.

```
$(document).on("click",".online",function() { 
    getMyId(this);    
});

function getMyId(element) {
    alert(element.id);
}
```

If you just wanted to pass the id through to the sub function you can do:

```
$(document).on("click",".online",function() { 
    getMyId(this.id);    
});

function getMyId(elementID) {
    alert(elementID);
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bdttvucy/2/) of it working

Answer (score 0):

check the below code snippet

```js
$(document).on("click", ".online", isInPrivateChat);

function isInPrivateChat(event) {
  anotherFunctin(event.currentTarget.id);
}

function anotherFunctin(id){
  console.log(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="online" id="id">
click me
</div>
```